# Lost internet access in Windows XP Mode Virtual PC under Windows 7

Tags: internet, connection, microsoft-virtual-pc

I also created and configured a Virtual PC in Windows XP mode. Both platforms functioned effectively for months. Now I've lost both internet connection and printer connection to a network printer, however, I can easily access shared data files from our server. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Has anything changed in your firewall settings or firewall software?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the network adapter type under Windows Virtual PC.
[This article might be of help](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824509)